# The best way to trigger resize for building jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, canvas, jquery-plugins

I'm building a jquery plugin (button with icon and notification), and I'm using canvas to draw a circle, I noticed that the resize event sometimes triggered and sometimes not, I'm using chrome for testing, this happen especially when I'm using maximize/restore button, and less when I'm resizing using the mouse (dragging)?

I think that maybe the resize event is triggered before the parent  is resized by the browser? or maybe I'm wrong? any suggestion :-)

[image]

And this after few clicks in resize/restore button of the brwoser:

[image]

Code (for drawing circle):

```
function createCanvas(obj) {                    
            canvas = $('<canvas style="z-index:10;position:relative;background-color:#b6d1aa"></canvas>').attr({
                width: $(obj).width(),
                height: dc_height
            }).appendTo(obj).get(0);    
            $(canvas).css({'top': (-1.8*btn_top).toString()+'px'});
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');                          
        }   
        /**
        * draw background circle
        */
        function drawBackCircle(){              
            var cntrX=$(obj).width()-($(obj).width()*0.1377777777777778);
            var cntrY=dc_height/2;
            var Radius=dc_height/2;
            context.fillStyle=customSettingsObj.fgcolor;                            
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(cntrX, cntrY, Radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);                              
            context.fill();                 
        }
```

Comment: Why do I get two (-)??? I'm not spamming !!!

Answer (score 0):

**I insist to get an answer "Why do I get two (-), you can't do that without explanation !!!!!**

I found a solution by using smartresize from [smartresize](https://github.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize)